# in or of in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Which one is correct? in or of?

> I would like to come back to Slovenia. If I do that , I'll make sure I can speak more ***in/of*** your
>   language.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you please provide some more context, as neither is incorrect as asked.

Comment: I've just edited it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe both are correct grammatically, and it depends on what you want to imply.

"of" would imply you want to be able to speak the language to a greater extent, have a greater knowledge of vocabulary and a better handle on how to speak the language so as to be able to speak it better. e.g. "I want to be able to speak more of the Slovenian language when I return."

"in" would imply you want to spend more time speaking that language versus the other. This might equally imply that you want to get better at the language, but has the connotation of time spent actively speaking one language over the other in regular conversation. e.g. "I want to speak more in Slovenian than in English when I return."

Answer (score 0):

Both prepositions are correct, but the difference lies in the connotation.

> I would like to come back to Slovenia. If I
>   do that, I will make sure I can speak more **in** your language.

Here, the preposition 'in' implies that you will make sure to converse **better** **in** the language.

> I would like to come back to Slovenia. If I
>   do that, I will make sure I can speak more **of** your language.

The preposition 'of' implies that you will make sure to **frequently use** the particular language more than other languages to communicate.